# jQuery show/hide is not working in a for loop

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have some link in my page which is given as display:none when loading and its id is dynamic.

```
<a href="#" ng-attr-id="{{ 'viewFile-' + $index }}" style="display:none" ng-click="showPreview(q.fileName,q.filePath)">{{q.fileName}}</a>
```

On load of page I gave

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.questions.length; x++) {
    if (data.questions[x].fileName == null) {
        $("#viewFile-" + x).hide();
    } else {
        $("#viewFile-" + x).show();
    }
}
```

Only the very first link ie. viewFile-0 is getting displayed, all others are hidden
While debugging the code, it is coming to the .show() line but in the page the link is not getting displayed.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Since you're using angularjs, I don't see why you need jQuery for that at all. I think you should try to avoid it and go with an angularjs solution. E.g. `ng-show=...` with a suitable condition

Comment: May be worth checking you don't have any css overrides? I think `!important` has precedence over inline styles. The code you've posted should work.

Comment: @molerat Thanks.It helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using **angularjs**, I don't see why you need jQuery for that at all.

I think you should try to avoid it and go with an angularjs solution. E.g. `ng-show=...` with a suitable condition.